# dispel error in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a query in SQL Server:

```
insert into [Sha1]( 
       [IDTbl]
      ,[IDTbl_old]
      ,[IDold]
      ,[WordsAsl])
 (SELECT  [IDTbl]
      ,[IDTbl_old]
      ,[IDold]
      ,[WordsAsl]
  FROM [Sha2])
```

How to solve this error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'IDTbl', table 'Sha1'; column
>   does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Comment: Have you considered that the answer you seek is in the error message you got. It is pretty clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other option besides just excluding those rows from your `SELECT` that contain `NULL` is to use the `ISNULL()` function to provide a default values instead of `NULL`:

```
 INSERT INTO dbo.Sha1(IDTbl, IDTbl_old, IDold, WordsAsl)
     SELECT  
        ISNULL(IDTbl, 42),
        IDTbl_old,
        IDold,
        WordsAsl
     FROM dbo.Sha2
```

Here I stipulated that should the `IDTbl` value from `dbo.Sha2` be `NULL`, then the `SELECT` should return 42 instead (and thus insert this value into `dbo.Sha1` instead of `NULL`).

Answer (score 1):

Some of the rows in your source table must contains `NULL` in the `IDTbl` field.

Try:

```
 insert into [Sha1]( 
   [IDTbl]
  ,[IDTbl_old]
  ,[IDold]
  ,[WordsAsl])
SELECT  [IDTbl]
  ,[IDTbl_old]
  ,[IDold]
  ,[WordsAsl]
FROM [Sha2]
WHERE IDTbl IS NOT NULL
```

You may find you need to make this `WHERE` clause more complex if other columns in the target table have contstraints.